# jQuery TOOLS scrollable circular bug

Tags: javascript, jquery-tools, scrollable

I've created a very simple jQuery TOOLS scrollable instance which is vertical and circular. There is an issue with it showing blank elements after a while.

Here's an example of the issue and all the code in jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ukQbm/